# How to keep asking the user for input until they choose to exit?

Tags: c, loops, random

How do I keep asking the user to input a number until they choose to exit? When I enter in another number, it doesn't keep going.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int numSets;
int a = 1, b = 53;    
int c;

int main()
{
    int ranOne, ranTwo, ranThree, ranFour, ranFive, ranSix;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Enter the amount of sets you want otherwise put -1 to exit:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numSets);

    for (c = 1; c <= numSets; c++) {
        ranOne = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
        ranTwo = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
        ranThree = (rand() % (b - a +1)) + a;
        ranFour = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
        ranFive = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
        ranSix = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;

        printf("Set # %d of six numbers: %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", c, ranOne, ranTwo, ranThree, ranFour, ranFive, ranSix);
    }

    if(numSets == -1) {
        printf("You have exited the application");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use another type of loop - a `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the logic you want to repeat into another loop, eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int numSets, ranOne, ranTwo, ranThree, ranFour, ranFive, ranSix;
    int a = 1, b = 53, c;

    srand(time(NULL));

    do {
        printf("Enter the amount of sets you want otherwise put -1 to exit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &numSets);

        if (numSets == -1) break;

        for (c = 1; c <= numSets; c++) {
            ranOne = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
            ranTwo = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
            ranThree = (rand() % (b - a +1)) + a;
            ranFour = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
            ranFive = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;
            ranSix = (rand() % (b - a + 1)) + a;

            printf("Set # %d of six numbers: %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", c, ranOne, ranTwo, ranThree, ranFour, ranFive, ranSix);
        }
    }
    while (1);

    printf("You have exited the application");

    return 0;
}
```